# Google App Maker app not working after deploy

Tags: google-app-maker

I have built an app with Google App Maker which has a Suggest Box linked to a table by a Query parameter.

The app works correctly in Preview mode, but when I deploy it, the Suggest Box doesn't suggest anything!

I have deployed it once before (without a select box as I recall) and it worked correctly.

I tried redeploying to the original deployment and deploying to a new deployment, same result.

Am I missing some security setting or something?

Comment: Is it a cloud sql data source?

Comment: No it's drive table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using Drive Tables as my datasource. The kind people at Google sent me a couple of links which helped me to understand what's going on: [previewing and publishing your application](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/deployment) and [running as user or developer](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/identity).

The crux of the issue is that when you deploy an app and run it as user (default), it doesn't take any Drive Table data with it. If you want to add Drive Table data to the deployed app, you have to do this:

1. Open App Maker
2. Go to App Settings
3. Go to Deployments
4. Select your most recent deployment and click: “EXPORT DATA”
5. Make sure you select Preview from the Deployments drop down list.
6. Click Export
7. This will export all your Preview data to a new Google Spreadsheet.
8. Now go to your Drive models in the App Maker and click “IMPORT DATA FROM SHEET”
9. Here you can choose to import data to your Deployed version.
10. After completing the import process, you will have all your data in the Deployed app.

All courtesy of Google but I didn't find it in the docs, so it might help someone.

Comment: Seems the documentation has the info available. [Check here](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/import-export)

Comment: That tells you how to import and export data, yes. It doesn't explain the process of deploying your application with its Drive Tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use the browser console to see if there's an error on the connection, make sure the user has access to the datasource and if you're using cloud SQL check the parameters of cloudSQL in the publication

Comment: No errors in the console, I checked. How do I ensure that the user has access to the data source? Not using cloudSQL.

Comment: You can check security settings under the Security tab in your model.By default it's Admins only. However if this was the cause I would expect an error in the console.