# Data within a published app maker deployment cant be seen by anyone and doesnt update

Tags: sql, google-app-maker

The issue is that once the app is deployed I (the creator) am able to view, edit and add records into the database but no one else can. When I give them the link the app loads as it should BUT none of the data is shown AND once they try to add their own record in the app it does not save nor am I able to view the added record on my end. I have tried to set the access to only a few people as regular users and I have tried selecting the "Do not restrict access to this application" field as well but none of those options work.

The closest issues to this I have found is this. 
[Google App Maker app not working after deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506938/google-app-maker-app-not-working-after-deploy)

And I import my data into the published deployment just as it states but after I send out the link to other people (They are within my domain as we are a on company email and that should work) it does not give them any access to view or add data.

I am wondering if it has anything to do with this section but am unsure. 
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT9s8.png)

I have published dozens of times at this point and I have not been able to find what the issue is. Is anyone else having this problem and found a solution?

Comment: In each of your data models what is your security setting? I believe App Maker still defaults all security settings for each model to 'Admins Only'. If that is the case you can go to each of your models, choose Security on the right hand side, and then choose advanced if you need to set different security levels for each of the different model events.

Comment: Yes that was definitely the problem! For whatever reason i figured the security settings on the deployment overrode those on the data model. Thank you!